# Why is Play not finding the view?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, view, playframework, playframework-2.0

This is my `show()` method for `UsersController`

```
import views.html.*;

public static Result show(Long id)
{
  User user = User.findById(id);

  return ok(views.html.users.show.render(user));
}
```

However, IntelliJ marks `show` as red and cannot find the symbol.

I already did `activator compile` and is `target` folder already has object `show.template.scala`.

Can anyone help me figure out what the problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: I assume that the project compiles successfully via `activator compile`. If so, have you tried invalidating your caches? File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart...

Comment: @edi Still doesn't help. Inteiilj seems to recognize the `show` refers to `views.html.users.show`, but when I use `Alt + Enter` to auto-complete, it still marks the `show` part red.

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like. Note the return type.

```
  public static Result show(Long id) {
    User user = User.findById(id);
    return ok(views.html.users.show.render(user));
  }
```

Also make sure you add this to you your routes file and ensure the the show.scala.html file is in a "/views/users" folder.

Comment: I don't see how different your code is from mine. I also do have `show.scala.html` in `/views/users` folder.

Comment: I see. I got the code wrong. I do have return type as `Result` instead of `void`. It was a typo in my question. But the problem's still there.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem every time that i created a new view in Eclipse. My solution was to refresh eclipse files with "play eclipse". In this case i think you have to find the way to make idea recognize the files (maybe "activator idea"?)

Comment: I did that, and it didn't help.